# Adding timestamps to empty lines in a text file

Tags: c++, file, timestamp

```
[00:00.00]
[00:54.25]1
[00:57.14]2
[01:01.04]3
[01:05.78]4
[01:08.03]5
[01:11.02]6
[01:14.21]7
[01:19.64]8

[01:21.83]9
[01:28.68]a
[01:33.34]b

[01:36.65]c
[01:40.58]d
```

Given the following text in a text file, for every blank line, I want to take the next line's timestamp, subtract it by 0.8, and put it in that blank line.

```
[00:00.00]
[00:54.25]1
[00:57.14]2
[01:01.04]3
[01:05.78]4
[01:08.03]5
[01:11.02]6
[01:14.21]7
[01:19.64]8
[01:21.03]
[01:21.83]9
[01:28.68]a
[01:33.34]b
[01:35.85]
[01:36.65]c
[01:40.58]d
```

Here's my current train of thought:
1) Copy a text file into a vector of char, appending char '\n' at end of every line.
2) Make a loop going through all the '\n' until it finds 2 of them in succession.
3) Once it does, it peeks at the next 9 characters (the timestamp excluding the last character ']'), and stores it into a variable.
4) Remove unnecessary characters '[' and ':', take the first 2 numbers, multiply by 60 (to make them seconds), and add it to the next 2 numbers and store it into an int.
5) Subtract that int by 0.8 and convert seconds into minutes, convert it into a char, then re-add the characters '[' and ':'.
6) Add in the timestamp and the character ']' between the two '\n'.
7) Cycle to the next '\n'.

So far I have only pushed the file into the vector and attempted to look for 2 new lines:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile("file.txt");
    vector<char> lineArray;
    string line;
    char newLine = '\n';
    ofstream outFile("newfile.txt");

    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        copy(line.begin(), line.end(), back_inserter(lineArray));
        lineArray.push_back(newLine);
    }
    for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = lineArray.begin(); i != lineArray.end(); ++i) 
        if (*i != '\n\n') {
            std::cout << *i;
        }

    system("pause");
}
```

Here are my following questions:
1) if (*i != '\n\n') has not worked. How do I check if *i is equal to 2 newlines?
2) How do you "peek" at the new few characters without iterating and store it into a variable?
3) How do you add the newly calculated timestamp in the middle of the vector while it's iterating?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the timestamps as you go?  If you encounter an empty line, set a flag and then when you read the next non-empty line, first push the adjusted empty timestamp, reset your flag and continue.  It's not clear what you want to do when you have multiple consecutive empty lines.  It's also not clear what you want to do if the timestamps separated by an empty line are less than 800 milliseconds apart.  Are you guaranteed that timestamps will always be less than 99:59.99?

Comment: I'll first answer your latter questions. There will not be any consecutively empty lines, guaranteed. If the timestamps separated by an empty line are less than 800 milliseconds apart, I would like it if the empty line had the average of the 2 timestamps. Yes, timestamp will be guaranteed less than 99:59.99. As for your first question, I'm not exactly sure how that is done.

Comment: *"Subtract that int by 0.8"* you won't be to happy with the result of substracting 0.8 from an integer. Better translate your whole timestamp to an integer (m*6000 + s*100 + fraction) and substract 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was okay, but you were maybe thinking too hard.  Rather than read all the data in and then attempt to process it later, it's easier to just process it as you go.

To read the timestamps, don't worry about looking ahead.  Simply use use `std::regex` to separate out the parts on the *current* line, and convert to an integer (that allows you to decide whether interpolation or offset is necessary).

Any non-empty line that doesn't match a timestamp pattern could be considered an error, but it might be fine to assume that a non-matching pattern is actually an empty line.  So my example would completely ignore any invalid lines.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::regex timestamp_regex( "^\\[(\\d+):([0-5]\\d).(\\d\\d)\\]");
    std::smatch match;
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    int last_timestamp = 0;
    bool empty_line = false;

    while( std::getline( std::cin, line ) )
    {
        // Consider non-matching regex to be empty line, instead of line.empty()
        if( std::regex_search( line, match, timestamp_regex ) )
        {
            int timestamp = std::stoi( match[1] ) * 6000
                + std::stoi( match[2] ) * 100 
                + std::stoi( match[3] );

            // Offset or interpolate timestamp for single empty line
            if( empty_line )
            {
                empty_line = false;
                int t = timestamp - 80;
                if( t < last_timestamp ) t = (last_timestamp + timestamp) / 2;
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << std::setfill('0') << '['
                    << std::setw(2) << (t/6000) << ':'
                    << std::setw(2) << (t/100%60) << '.'
                    << std::setw(2) << (t % 100) << ']';
                lines.emplace_back( oss.str() );
            }
            last_timestamp = timestamp;
            lines.push_back( line );
        }
        else
        {
            empty_line = true;
        }
    }

    // Display all the lines
    for( auto & line : lines )
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a link to a [working example](http://ideone.com/7krObA) -- I should point out that the compiler should support C++11 as a minimum.

Note that the lines are all stored as a vector of strings.  But if you insist on having a single contiguous vector of bytes, it's a trivial modification.

Also, if your timestamps are not in chronological order, you will have unexpected results.

If you *really* want answers to your 3 questions, I suppose that could be addressed in a separate answer.  But your questions come from a messy approach, and require messy solutions.  And maybe you just don't want to go there.

Comment: Of curiosity's sake I am highly interested in how all this works. If you have time I am more than happy to read your reasoning and your answers. But, the solution you gave me is plenty and thus I will mark it as solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which parts of the solution do you need help understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this which uses [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, header-only date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) for the parsing and formatting of the time stamp, and `<chrono>` for the time stamp computations.  It requires C++11, C++14 or C++17 as it is based on `<chrono>` which wasn't introduced until C++11.  It is portable across Windows, gcc and clang (and possibly others).

```
#include "date.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ifstream inFile{"file.txt"};
    ofstream outFile{"newfile.txt"};
    string linenumber;
    istringstream in;
    using centiseconds = chrono::duration<int, centi>;
    centiseconds last_ts{0};
    constexpr centiseconds ts80{80};
    constexpr auto fmt = "[%M:%S]";
    while (inFile)
    {
        // Try to parse a time stamp
        centiseconds ts;
        inFile >> date::parse(fmt, ts);
        if (inFile.fail())
        {
            // Didn't work.  End of file?
            if (inFile.eof())
                break;
            // Ok, assume a blank line and consume it
            inFile.clear();
            inFile.ignore(1, '\n');
            // parse next line and assume it is a valid time stamp
            inFile >> date::parse(fmt, ts);
            assert(!inFile.fail());
            // Create and format the interpolated time stamp
            auto its = ts - last_ts < ts80 ? (ts + last_ts) / 2 : ts - ts80;
            outFile << date::format(fmt, its) << '\n';
        }
        getline(inFile, linenumber);  // parse optional line number
        // Format current time stamp, unchanged.
        outFile << date::format(fmt, ts) << linenumber << '\n';
        last_ts = ts;
    }
}
```

1. The first thing to do is to create a custom `chrono::duration` for the desired precision: `centiseconds`.
2. Next set up some constants.  The `fmt = "[%M:%S]"` string is used both for parsing and formatting the time stamp.
3. While the input file is good:

   A. Try to parse a time stamp.

   B. If the parse failed, and we haven't hit end-of-file, consume the blank line.

   C.  Parse the time stamp after the blank line.

   D.  Compute the interpolated time stamp and format it out.

   E.  Parse the optional line number for the current time stamp and then format everything back out.

   F.  Remember the time stamp for the next iteration so that an average can be made if required.

This formulation requires no `vector` to store the entire input file in.  You simply output as you go, line by line.

You can't (easily) use `strptime`/`strftime`/`get_time`/`put_time` for the parsing and formatting because they don't handle sub-second precision.

Note the lack of manual time-units conversions.  This eliminates a common source of errors.